# Keyboard navigation for cbp full width slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, keyboard-navigation

Had tried this [JS-FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tata93/u636qeqs/4/)  But did not succeed. Can some one help out, How to enable the keyboard navigation for this slider.

```
_toggleNavControls : function() {

        // if the current item is the first one in the list, the left arrow is not shown
        // if the current item is the last one in the list, the right arrow is not shown
        switch( this.current ) {
            case 0 : this.$navNext.show(); this.$navPrev.hide(); break;
            case this.itemsCount - 1 : this.$navNext.hide(); this.$navPrev.show(); break;
            default : this.$navNext.show(); this.$navPrev.show(); break;
        }
        // highlight navigation dot
        this.$navDots.eq( this.old ).removeClass( 'cbp-fwcurrent' ).end().eq( this.current ).addClass( 'cbp-fwcurrent' );

    }
```

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with keyboard navigation ? do you want to control the slider by the arrows on the keyboard ??

Comment: Absolutely ! I want to control my slides with keyboard and  mouse. @Anas Omar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[see demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u636qeqs/6/)

You need to bind a keydown event on document in _initEvents functions and watch the left and right arrow keys for being pressed:

```
$(document).keydown(keyHandler);

function keyHandler(event)  { 
        if (event.keyCode === 39) {

           if(self.$navNext.is(":visible")) self.$navNext.trigger("click.cbpFWSlider");
            return false;
          } else if (event.keyCode === 37) {
            if(self.$navPrev.is(":visible")) self.$navPrev.trigger("click.cbpFWSlider");
            return false;
          }

    };
```

P.S. In Jsfiddle do not forget to put focus in the preview area by clicking on it - the right bottom part, so the keys are being watched.